# Why does Android kill my BROWSABLE activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm writing an enterprise application that needs to process some data in the background while the user is using an intranet website. The application's manifest properly declares the BROWSABLE intent filter, and the browser properly starts it via JavaScript.

Typically, the application is invisible to the user, so the application just passes parameters from the URI JavaScript is calling to the background service and terminates itself. On occasion however, some of the background services require user interaction. In this case, the main activity DOESN'T terminate; instead, it prompts the user for whatever information/action is needed, and only terminates when all the conditions are met.

**All of the above works perfectly** as long as the application is triggered from the browser as a result of a direct user interaction (user clicks on a control -> a JavaScript function is called -> the JS function requests an URI registered with the application -> my application is displayed and waits for user input).

However, if the JS is called without direct user interaction in the web page (e.g. from an onLoad() event handler) then the application is started properly, but then it's terminated by the OS almost instantly, without any errors/exceptions thrown. I simply get a call to onPause(), then onDestroy(), and that's it. The background service continues to run, but the main activity is gone, and with it any chance to interact with the user.

Does anyone have any idea why it's exhibiting this behavior and how I could inhibit or work around it?

**UPDATE:** If I set `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest, the application behaves consistently, as expected. In my specific case, this solves the problem, but I still don't understand the general behavior.